# Convert event time into date and time in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have below event_time in my data frame

[image]

I would like to convert the event_time into date/time. Used below code, however it's not coming properly

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn("date", f.from_unixtime("Event_Time", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"))
df.show()
```

I am getting below output and it's not coming properly

[image]

Can anyone advise how to do this properly as I am new to pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your data is in Microseconds (1/1,000,000 second) so you would have to divide by 1,000,000

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('1645904274665267',),
('1645973845823770',),
('1644134156697560',),
('1644722868485010',),
('1644805678702121',),
('1645071502180365',),
('1644220446396240',),
('1645736052650785',),
('1646006645296010',),
('1644544811297016',),
('1644614023559317',),
('1644291365608571',),
('1645643575551339',)
  ], ['Event_Time']
)

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn("date", f.from_unixtime(f.col("Event_Time")/1000000))
df.show(truncate = False)
```

output

```
+----------------+-------------------+
|Event_Time      |date               |
+----------------+-------------------+
|1645904274665267|2022-02-26 20:37:54|
|1645973845823770|2022-02-27 15:57:25|
|1644134156697560|2022-02-06 08:55:56|
|1644722868485010|2022-02-13 04:27:48|
|1644805678702121|2022-02-14 03:27:58|
|1645071502180365|2022-02-17 05:18:22|
|1644220446396240|2022-02-07 08:54:06|
|1645736052650785|2022-02-24 21:54:12|
|1646006645296010|2022-02-28 01:04:05|
|1644544811297016|2022-02-11 03:00:11|
|1644614023559317|2022-02-11 22:13:43|
|1644291365608571|2022-02-08 04:36:05|
|1645643575551339|2022-02-23 20:12:55|
+----------------+-------------------+
```